# Stripe Subscription Schedules Charge Instantly instead of waiting one hour

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

For some reason, when you create a "Subscription Schedules" stripe, it has very odd behavior where instead of trying to charge the customer, it keeps the invoice in draft for 1 hour and then closes the invoice and charges the customer.

I already have the card in the customer. I wonder if there is any way I can force the first phase of the subscription to be charged immediately.

My code:

```
  $phases = [
    [
      'items' => [
                     [
                       'price_data' => [
                       'currency' => 'usd',
                       'product' => $product->stripe_product_id,
                       'recurring' => [
                           'interval' => $payment_plan['frequency'],
                       ],
                       'unit_amount' => $payment_plan['stripe_amount']
                     ],
                     'quantity' => 1,
                ],
             ],
             'iterations' => (int) $payment_plan['total_payments']
            ],
        ];

       $subscription = $stripe->subscriptionSchedules->create([
                    'customer' => $customer->stripe_customer_id,
                    'start_date' => 'now',
                    'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
                    'phases' => $phases,
       ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$subscription = $stripe->subscriptionSchedules->create([
                    'customer' => $customer->stripe_customer_id,
                    'start_date' => 'now',
                    'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
                    'phases' => $phases,
]);

  // now the invoice is a draft so we go get this invoice
$invoice = $stripe->invoices->all([
                    'limit' => 3, 
                    'status' => 'draft',
                    'subscription' => $subscription->subscription,
                    'customer' => $customer->stripe_customer_id,
]);

//get the most recent draft
$invoice = $invoice->data[0];

//finalize the invoice (but this don't generate the payment for some reason)
$stripe->invoices->finalizeInvoice(
$invoice->id, [
'auto_advance' => true
]
);

//finaly pay the invoice
$invoice = $stripe->invoices->pay($invoice->id,[
'payment_method' => $token
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a subscription immediately, you can do that without a Subscription Schedule and then set the schedule for that existing subscription:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription

Alternatively, if creating with the schedule like you're doing, once the subscription/invoice is created (as a draft) you can use the API to finalize it manually to proceed with the payment:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/finalize

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Finalize the invoice it self is not enought to generate the payment but was helpful.

Comment: If the Invoice is allowed to `auto_advance` then I'd expect finalization to proceed to payment (asynchronously). You could also call `/pay` to trigger it yourself (this also finalized if not yet finalized).